# Selenium RC is feasible to firefox 15 and windows 7?

Tags: selenium-rc

I tried to open a link in Firefox 15 by using selenium RC.

Not able to open the link and it throws error "www.cfauth.com".

I wanna know if Selenium RC is compatible with Firefox 15 and windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Selenium RC with Firefox 15 and Windows 7 should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium RC works fine till Firefox version 5..As RC is officially depreciated,there is no longer support for advancements in browser .Possible solution is to switch to selenium Webdriver.